# Creating Facebook test user friendship returns "(#532) You can't add this user as a friend"

Tags: facebook, testing, rest, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a script to create test data for my application. The script first creates a collection of test users, and then assigns friendships between them.

I create a friendship between two test users with 
`https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_USER_1_ID/friends/TEST_USER_2_ID?method=post&access_token=TEST_USER_1_ACCESS_TOKEN`

However for random users, any friend request involving the user has the response
`{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#532) You can't add this user as a friend"}}`

I can't find anything about this error message.

Answer (score 2):

That's because a normal user can't be friends with a test user. The test user is visible only within the scope of an application, not outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain my case in which both users are test users for the same application.

Comment: sorry ... misunderstood your question. There are two options here: 1st: test users can't be friends and 2nd: try replacing the test_user_1_access_token with the application access token, which you can obtain by hitting https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials. Hope that helps!

Comment: actually test users CAN be friends, because I've made test users friends before, but via the UI, please check if the app access token  works for you